# Conditional if print dates in wrong date rows in table in django

Tags: python, django, date

I want to print some messages in those dates which were shifted from previous dates. For that I have two Models one for storing both previous dates and new dates in the same sit_date field. This model is:

```
class Sitting(models.Model):
    sit_date = models.DateField(blank=False,unique=True)
    cut_off_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    ballot_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    sess_no = models.ForeignKey(Session,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    genre = TreeForeignKey('Genre', null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
```

Another model for creating shift dates using the sit_date of above model. When I created shift dates this dates are stored in the sit_date field of Sitting model. Here is my second model:

```
class Shiftdate(models.Model):
    shift_date = models.DateField(blank=False,unique=True)
    sit_date = models.ForeignKey(Sitting,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shift_cut_off_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    shift_ballot_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    sess_no = models.ForeignKey(Session,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    genre = TreeForeignKey('Genre', null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
```

After that when render sit_date in the template, I want to check which sit_dates are equal to the sit_dates of Shiftdate model. If found there should be a message print on the shift dates rows in the table. For that so far I get following code in my template:

```
{% for sitting in c.sittings %}
    {% for shiftdate in sitting.shiftdate_set.all %}
        {% if sittings.sit_date == shiftdate.sit_date %}
            <p>Firstly it was scheduled on {{sitting.shift_date}}</p>
        {% endif %}       
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But It printed the messages on the original sit_date not the shifting date rows. Here is the output:[image]

In the above table you can see my original sit_dates are 31 August and 1 September and my shifting dates are 14 and 15 September. But messages "Firstly it was scheduled on {{shiftdate.sit_date}}" printed on the original sit_date instead of shifted dates which is now also sit_date in the Sitting model.

Could someone suggest the ways to fix this?

Comment: I think it should be `{% if sitting.sit_date == shiftdate.sit_date %}` instead of `{% if sittings.sit_date == shiftdate.sit_date %}` (`sitting` instead of `sittings`)

Comment: It doesn't help. It even don't show any data.